# Spinner disapear after setOnSelectedListener doing some query

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-spinner

I want to build Download Activity, the data loaded from firebase. The activity has one spinner and one recyclerview .

Im using Default Spinner Android

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.yehezkiel.eclassapp.MateriActivity">


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Spinner>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_materi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="56dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

java:

```
   final Spinner areaSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    areaSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);




    userRef.child(users.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                for(DataSnapshot dataHasil :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String nama_matkul = (String) dataHasil.getValue();
                    key.add(nama_matkul);
                    final String idCourses = dataHasil.getKey();



                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> areasAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MateriActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, key);
                areasAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                areaSpinner.setAdapter(areasAdapter);




            }else{

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}



@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long l) {
    final String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    listMateri.clear();

    materiRef.child(item).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                MateriKuliah materi = dataSnapshot.getValue(MateriKuliah.class);

                listMateri.add(materi);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }else{
                Snackbar.make(view, "Tidak ada Materi " , Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}
```

My Achievement is when I select the spinner, and then recyclerview will populate it with firebase data. When I selected the empty data, spinner still doing good and no problem.

The problem is when data from firebase populate the recyclerview, then spinner disapear. I dont know what happen here.

My app video and the problem : https://streamable.com/6ikba

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because you have used `ConstraintLayout` and you have't set constraints for the layout so what is happening here is `Recyclerview` is overlapping the spinner after it gets enough data to cover the screen. So what you can do here is set constraints or use any other `Viewgroup` like `RelativeLayout` which can be handy in your case.

You can learn more about `ConstraintLayout` here: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/

Comment: Thanksssss a lot mate

Comment: Glad i could help.If it worked for you please accept the answer so others can get help as well.

Comment: Sir,one more problem is. When the activity start,the first data which is Rekayasa Perangkat Lunak doesn't displaying the data in recyclerview. Can you help me?

Comment: It is happening because onItemSelected of spinner is not called for the very first time in your given library unless you select the item, if you switch items and select that item again you will see results.In android default spinner method is called so this seems like a library limitation.

Comment: From your answer ,I can take the conclusion this because of the library sir?

Comment: Yes,You can confirm it by using default spinner provided in android studio.

Comment: Sir I updated the code and the xml with default spinner. The problem that was nothing apear when the first spinner item is solved now. But now I have another problem, when i selected spinner item that dont have recyclerview, the recyclerview is still populate with the last item. Check the video thanks.

Comment: For that you have to ask new question and start another thread describe your problem there because that would be different from the question you asked earlier here.So that users don't get confused who visit this question.Hope you get it.